# Hibernate search can be used with eclipse JPA provider?

Tags: java, jpa, search, eclipselink, hibernate-search

Hibernate search can be used with eclipse JPA provider?

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

---

I have this exception when using Hibernate search with eclipselink JPA.

```
 FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(ClientEntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager());


// create native Lucene query unsing the query DSL
// alternatively you can write the Lucene query using the Lucene query parser
// or the Lucene programmatic API. The Hibernate Search DSL is recommended though
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(WikiPage.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
  .keyword()
  //.onFields("name", "content", "authors.name")
        .onFields("name", "content", "pageSummary")
  .matching("wiki")
  .createQuery();
```

**Exception content:**

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Trying to use Hibernate Search without an Hibernate EntityManager: class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl

Comment: Well since Hibernate Envers and Search are built on HIBERNATE, then you need Hibernate ...

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Search forces you to use Hibernate as your JPA2 implementation. You can not use EclipseLink with Hibernate Search.

There is a project that enables EclipseLink and other JPA2 implementations to use Hibernate Search here:

https://github.com/s4ke/hibernate-search/tree/genericjpa/genericjpa